# Encoding when saving to clipboard with pyperclip in tkinter script

Tags: python, tkinter, pyperclip

I am putting together a client in **Python 3.5** that can be used to retrieve completed translation jobs from a site. I decided to use buttons that copy the translated content to the clipboard for usability reasons. Depending on whether the translation is a plain text or saved in a file, the buttons display either "Download" or "Copy to clipboard".

It is working for the most part - I can copy and paste texts in English with no problem by clicking the button and then pasting the contents to a text editor.

Unfortunately, I get some funky characters when dealing with German (stuff like ä, ö and ü) and Japanese turns into mush.

```
 def retrieveJobs(self):

     availableJobIDs = gengo.getTranslationJobs(status='reviewable')['response']

         text_count = 0
         text_dict = {}
         file_count = 0
         file_dict = {}

         for i in range(len(availableJobIDs)):

         job = gengo.getTranslationJob(id=availableJobIDs[i]['job_id'])['response']['job']

         title = job['slug']
         titleLabel = tk.Label(self, text=title)
         titleLabel.grid(row=i+3, sticky=tk.E)


         if 'file_url_tgt' in job.keys():
                link = job['file_url_tgt']
                file_dict[file_count] = link
                linkButton = tk.Button(self, text='ダウンロード', 
                                       command=lambda file_count=file_count: urllib.request.urlopen(url=file_dict[file_count]))
                linkButton.grid(row=i+3, column=1, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)
                file_count += 1
         else:
                text = job['body_tgt']
                text_dict[text_count] = text
                copyButton = tk.Button(self, text='訳文をコピーする', 
                                       command=lambda text_count=text_count: tk.clipboard_append(text_dict[text_count]))
                copyButton.grid(row=i+3, column=1, sticky=tk.W)
                text_count += 1
```

The head of the script is marked with

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

However, when I press one of the buttons to copy a text in Japanese, like

```
これはどのように動作し、すべての順序のどこに表示する短いテキストです。
```

(don't mind the meaning, it's gibberish) and copy it to a Word file, the resulting text looks like this:

```
„Åì„Çå„ÅØ„Å©„ÅÆ„Çà„ÅÜ„Å´Âãï‰Ωú„Åó„ÄÅ„Åô„Åπ„Å¶„ÅÆÈ†ÜÂ∫è„ÅÆ„Å©„Åì„Å´Ë°®Á§∫„Åô„ÇãÁü≠„ÅÑ„ÉÜ„Ç≠„Çπ„Éà„Åß„Åô„ÄÇ
```

How can I modify the code to display Japanese characters properly? As seen in the code, the text is stored in a dictionary and, at that point, is still intact. Only when pulling it out with pyperclip does it turn all funky.

I hope the explanation is sufficient.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Python 2.x or 3?

Comment: Sorry, 3.5. Will add to the description!

Comment: The `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` only tells the python compiler that your source code is encoded in utf8.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! So I need to tell pyperclip to fetch the information in UTF-8 separately? How do I go about on doing this?

Comment: Hi @Vash, are you using `pyperclip`? In your code, I only see `clipboard_append()`...

Comment: Hello, Josselin. I have indeed tried to implement clipboard_append, seeing as it is part of tkinter, but without much luck. I reversed that part very quickly, but apparently, I have posted an in-between version. Thank you for the input!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I only had to make a small adjustment here:

```
copyButton = tk.Button(self, 
                       text='訳文をコピーする', 
                       command=lambda text_count=text_count: tk.clipboard_append(text_dict[text_count]))
```

The functioning version looks like this:

```
copyButton = tk.Button(self, 
                       text='訳文をコピーする', 
                       command=lambda text_count=text_count: root.clipboard_append(text_dict[text_count]))
```

No more funky characters in either German or Japanese. Other languages such as French and Chinese are now functional, as well.

Thank you again for the input! It helped a lot to get a new perspective on the code.

Comment: The `root` points to the main frame (via the `tk.Tk()` method) of the program, that is initiated after all classes are defined. 

I decided to try and bind the copy method to different levels of the program and started with the most basic one, the `root` window. To my surprise, it worked immediately.